# Publishing WinForms application as html 5 canvas

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html5-canvas, vnc

We've got a decent sized WinForms application that we are gradually replacing with a mvc web application.

I'd like to find a way of publishing portions of our WinForms application via a screen scraping tool or similar, so that we don't have to rewrite the full application in mvc. This would be especially useful for the the lesser used portions of the application (like configuration etc).

I've had a bit of a play with ThinVNC which works great, but because it uses screen scraping, it seems limited to how many instances of the WinForms app you could run up and publish at any one time (as the screen size is only so big). I haven't been able to get ThinVNC to work with RDP sessions (in an effort to have multiple sessions running).

Has anyone got any ideas of approaches to do this?

Comment: VNC/RDP is not "screen scraping" :)

Comment: Well ThinVNC doesn't actually implement VNC, but I do believe it screen scrapes

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer can host Windows Forms in a web page:

> http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx